# Question which has no answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry, I don't really know how to improve this question, this quiz has been given me today and I think there is no a true answer, because in the different cases of $a > 0, a < 0, b > 0, b < 0$(and nested cases) you have that every answer can be false.

Taken $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, given $a^2 - b^2 = 0$, which one is true?

1. $ab > 0$
2. $a + b = 1$
3. $ab < -1$
4. $a > b$
5. $a + b = 0$

These are answers I gave myself(all the examples respect the given condition of $a^2 - b^2 = 0$:

1. If $a = 1 \land b = -1$ then $ab = -1$
2. If $a = 1 \land b = -1$ then $a + b = 0$
3. If $a = 0 \land b = 0$ then $ab = 0$
4. If $a = -1 \land b = 1$ then $a < b$
5. If $a = 1 \land b = 1$ then $a + b = 2$

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, it does seem like none of them are true. If they had specified $a\neq b$ then the last one would have been true.

Comment: Assuming R is $\mathbb{R}$, there is no answer which is always true

Answer (score 4):

All of the options are false, your couter-examples are okay. Some statements you can get from $a^2 - b^2 = 0, a,b \in \mathbb R$ are:
$$\begin{align*}a^2 & = b^2\\|a|^2 & = |b|^2\\|a| &= |b|\\a&=\pm b\\b&=\pm a\end{align*}$$

Comment: These are statements I already found myself, thanks anyway! I'll ask the teacher to make it clear.

Comment: @LightStyle I guess you answered the question by yourself anyways ;-) multiple choice does not imply that at least one answer is correct ^^

Comment: Yep I only wanted to be totally sure before making a dumb question to the teacher :P however this specific question had to have an answer, since it was inside a test :P

Comment: @LightStyle Proof by counter-example :P My Profs (if they have MC, it's not very usual here) explicitly say that any and all or none may also be a correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

since a<sup>2</sup> - b<sup>2</sup> = 0
by factorization
(a+b)(a-b) = 0

a + b = 0 and a - b = 0

Thus , among all options last one a + b = 0 is correct

Comment: Not necessarily - EITHER a + b =0 OR a - b = 0. So it is not a necessity that a + b = 0

Comment: Look at the counter example provided by the OP. The last one is not guaranteed to be true just because $a^2-b^2=0$

Comment: $ab = 0 \Leftrightarrow a = 0 \vee b = 0$ note the big **OR** ($\vee$). This is wrong, the OP even gave a counter-example.